# Many specific object properties to array

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-sqlite3

I use sqlite3 in my express app, and when user add new account to my system I use this code to add info to database:

```
db.run(`INSERT INTO accounts(uuid, email, pass, device, user, pet, gold, is_active) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`,
    [this.uuid, this.email, this.pass, this.device, this.user, this.pet, this.gold, this.is_active],
    function (err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log(err.message);
        }
    });
```

db - is my sqlite3 instance

I am sure there is should be a way to code it better (maybe something with spread? ).
But I don't understand how to get only specific properties from 'this' (it contains other properties, that i don't need in my database)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an array of the properties to extract from `this`, then `.map` it:

```
const props = 'uuid email pass device user pet gold is_active'.split(' ');
db.run(
  `INSERT INTO accounts(uuid, email, pass, device, user, pet, gold, is_active) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`,
  props.map(prop => this[prop]),
  function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err.message);
    }
  }
);
```

Could be even less repetitive (and less error-prone) by saving the string of properties so you can both split on it *and* pass to the first argument of `.run`:

```
const propsStr = 'uuid, email, pass, device, user, pet, gold, is_active';
const props = propsStr.split(', ');
db.run(
  `INSERT INTO accounts(${propsStr}) VALUES(${propsStr.replace(/\w+/g, '?')})`,
  props.map(prop => this[prop]),
  function(err) {
    if (err) {
      return console.log(err.message);
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: Maybe add props.join(', ') in first example to add it like that  `INSERT INTO accounts(${props.join(', ')}) VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)`,

Comment: Could also use `VALUES(${Array(props.length).fill("?").join(", ")})` so you don't have to count and type out all those question marks.

Comment: I too think so. Thanks a lot to you guys!